# Azure Devops YAML Pipeline Trigger on different repositories

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to have a yaml pipeline trigger on commits/PRs for branches of different repositories (e.g. Repo A) to the one the azure-pipelines.yaml file is in (e.g. Repo B)?

I'm aware I can build the pipeline against Repo B and have it checkout Repo A using e.g:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Repo A
    type: github
    endpoint: ***
    name: ***/RepoA

trigger:
 - master
```

But the trigger is only applying to Repo B, i.e. when I make a commit on master to Repo A, the pipeline does not trigger.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The "Sprint 173" release seems to be including the [multi-repo triggers feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-173-update#multi-repo-triggers). I suspect you might be missing the ref.

> Here is an example that shows how to define multiple repository
> resources in a pipeline and how to configure triggers on all of them.
>
> ```
> trigger:
> - main
>
> resources:
>   repositories:
>   - repository: tools
>     type: git
>     name: MyProject/tools
>     ref: main
>     trigger:
>       branches:
>         include:
>         - main
>         - release
> ```
>
> The pipeline in this example will be triggered if there are any
> updates to:
>
> - `main` branch in the `self` repo containing the YAML file
> - `main` or `release` branches in tools repo

Comment: That looks good - sadly it seems not supported with github.

Comment: All of my internal stuff completely within Azure DevOps, so hard for me to say.  The [full documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#specify-multiple-repositories) specifically mentions GitHub repos though in the support list.

Comment: Ok interesting - I'll check if it works with pr triggers too, but from the docs it looks like it should.  I'll test soon and change the accepted answer if this is working.  Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm. Thankyou!

Comment: I tried to follow the steps, but pipelines can not be triggered on `MyProject/tools` change, how to track the issue down ?

Comment: @whisper hard to say without seeing the configuration.  Maybe post a new question and reference how your configuration (include it) is different than this question and someone can say whether you have a different issue or not.

Comment: @Matt Do you know if there is any way to achieve this in Classis builds? Our on-premise environment is still on Azure DevOps 2017

Comment: @Fairoz Probably not on one build definition.  In the classic designer, they have triggers for build completion to trigger other pipelines.  There are marketplace tasks for triggering other pipelines.  You could probably handle it via that mechanism.  Unsure of your full requirements, so if you ask that as a question you'd probably get some examples.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Multi-repo triggers is supported for Github repo resources yet.

As it is said in the document:

> Repository resource triggers only work for Azure Repos Git repositories at present. They do not work for GitHub or Bitbucket repository resources.

If you were using Azure Repos Git repositories. You need to specify the **trigger** section for the repository resources in order to enable the Multi-repo triggers. See document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers) for more information.

Since you are using github, you can use **[pipeline completion triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)** as workaround. You can refer to below steps to setup a pipeline completion trigger for RepoB pipeline.

1, Set up the **triggering pipeline** for RepoA.

You can create a pipeline for github RepoA in azure devops. Classic UI pipeline is recommanded, for it won't add a azure-pipelines.yaml file in your RepoA.

I suggest you add a empty agent job(without any tasks)in the triggering pipeline. So that the pipeline run will always be successful.

[image]

You need to **Enable continuous integration** for this triggering pipeline. So that the  commits/PRs for branches in RepoA will automatically trigger this pipeline.

In the pipeline **Edit** page, Go to **Triggers** tab, Check `Enable continuous integration`, Add the branches you want to enable CI in the Branches Filters section

[image]

2, Set up pipeline resources in triggered pipeline (ie. azure-pipelines.yaml file for RepoB)

Add the [pipeline resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-pipelines) and specify the trigger section in the pipeline resource. See below example:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: Repo A 
    type: github
    endpoint: ***
    name: ***/RepoA

  pipelines:
  - pipeline: repoAPipeline   # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: triggeringPipeline-RepoA # Name of the triggering pipeline
    trigger: 
      branches:
      - releases/*
      - master
```

When changes are made to RepoA, the triggering pipeline will be triggered and complete successfully. When the triggering pipeline is completed, Pipeline for RepoB will be triggered.

By setting up the triggering pipeline for RepoA and the pipeline resources in pipeline of RepoB. You can achieve the same effect with Multi-repo triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve recently discovered a workaround that addresses the issue with Multi-Repo trigger for **GitHub** in Azure CI integration. This involves leveraging the existing webhook service connection to manually configure a trigger. More information can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#define-a-webhooks-resource).

```
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: WebHookAlias #Webhook alias name
      connection: IncomingWH #Webhook service connection name
steps:
#Access webhook values
 - script: echo ${{ parameters.WebHookAlias.<json_path> }}
```

I’ve also detailed how to use the status check API in GitHub to ensure that the pull request is not processed until the pipeline is successful. This solution effectively addresses the issue at hand. You can find more details [here](https://medium.com/@aabeing/multi-repo-trigger-in-azure-devops-f1c4cf84761f).