# Azure Devops Pipeline Trigger Path Include and Exclude Other Projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a repo setup similar to the following

- common/
- projects/FirstProj
- projects/AnotherProj
- projects/ProjTheThird

and I have a pipeline for each project

- FirstProj-Pipeline
- AnotherProj-Pipeline
- ProjTheThird-Pipeline

I would like to setup the trigger so that when I commit to one of the folders in 'projects' the pipeline specific to that project will trigger (and only that pipeline)

Example trigger for FirstProj:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - '**'
    - projects/FirstProj
    exclude:
    - projects/**
```

I would have expected this to trigger for (and only for) commits to 'projects/FirstProj' and 'common/'
But it did not trigger for commits to 'projects/FirstProj', I assume the exclude is taking priority over the include

How do I setup the trigger so that I do not have to have a specific exclude for the other projects for every project pipeline?
And not have to go back and add an exclude to other projects yml any time I add a new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would have expected this to trigger for (and only for) commits to
> 'projects/FirstProj' and 'common/' But it did not trigger for commits
> to 'projects/FirstProj'.

It is unreachable through out-of-box settings. Your triggers will work for `common` or `projects/FirstProj` commits.

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - '**'
    - projects/FirstProj
    exclude:
    - projects/**
```

The trigger does not support `and` for `include` section. As a workaround, you may try to call `git diff` and stop the build if you do not detect all needed changes.

Comment: Thanks I had suspected this - I have had to just resort to explicit excludes for "other" projects per projects pipeline

Answer (score 0):

The trigger path functionality is based on the path within the repository that the yaml file is stored in, not all repositories in the project. Adding `projects/FirstProj` to attempt to path to your project is invalid. What that would be attempting to do is only trigger for changed files in the `projects/FirstProj` folders in that same repository, which I imagine does not exist in your case, which is may be why it's not triggering.

You do not need to add excludes for other repositories because the trigger is designed to only trigger for file paths within the repository.

---

If you did however wish to trigger other repositories, the yaml would look something like this:

```
trigger:
- main

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: projects/AnotherProj
    type: git
    name: AnotherProj
    ref: main
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - main
        - release
```

Reading list:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/trigger?view=azure-pipelines
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines
- [Azure Devops YAML Pipeline Trigger on different repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63268986/azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-trigger-on-different-repositories)

Answer (score 0):

The trigger settings for FirstProj-Pipeline:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - common
    - projects/FirstProj
```

The trigger settings for AnotherProj-Pipeline:

```
trigger:
  paths:
    include:
    - common
    - projects/AnotherProj
```

For ProjTheThird-Pipeline, use a similar path filter. Just add `common` and `projects/ProjTheThird` to the included filter.

- Make changes in common folder: All pipelines will be triggered.
- Make changes in projects/FirstProj folder: Only FirstProj-Pipeline will be triggered.
- Make changes in projects/AnotherProj folder: Only AnotherProj-Pipeline will be triggered.

See more info about path filter in the trigger from [Paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths).